# React Router V6 - I am currently working on on my first (SPA) to which i have come across a run time error that i can not solve

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My application is a simple Single Page App (SPA) that working fine until I started working with `react-router-dom`.

After following some of the documentation that was provided by React.dev, W3 schools, surrounding `BrowserRouter` and its means to link pages together. After adding the `BrowerRouter`, `Router` `Routes`, `Route` my to SPA  it wont display in Google Chrome. This is my code as follows:

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Nav";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import './styles/Styles.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <div className="Navbar">
            <h1>This is the Navbar</h1>
          </div>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
  return(
    <div className="home">
      <h1>This is a Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Please note that all pages are set up to be basic and pretty much the same code as home.js

The errors that I have are in the web browser take me to https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call.

After checking My.lib and my.app using npm ls to check for duplication of installed files there is no duplication.

Comment: What is the error? Is it the `Router` rendered within another router, i.e. the `BrowserRouter`? Please also [edit] the code to include your code as properly formatted and readable code snippets instead of images of code, the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, and a [mcve] of the relevant code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pastable for reproducibility purposes.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that stands out; you're not directly using any hooks so I don't know why it would give you that error. Please add the full stack trace of your error, that might help.

Comment: I didn't think there was anything wrong with the code. Because I have tried other very versions of the browser router. For instance there is a version where you can wrap the browser router around the code in the app.js file. And just pass the app in the index.js.

Comment: The only issue I see is using both a `BrowserRouter` and `Router`. Just use the `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Are you saying replace the router with browser router?

Comment: The error is a react.development.js 209 invalid hook call

Comment: No, I'm saying to remove the extraneous `Router` component in the `App` component. It's unnecessary since the parent component is already rendering a `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: So after changing the code by removing the Router from the App.js it still continues to throw 209 invalid hook call